# SceneKit Animations on DefaultCameraController

Tags: scenekit, scnnode, scnscene, scncamera

and pardon my ignorance here. I am brand new with SceneKit. I am trying to get my default camera controller to animate with a sort of smooth "panning motion". I am trying to use something like:

```
scnView.defaultCameraController.translateInCameraSpaceBy(x: 10, y: 10, z: 10)
```

When the `SCNView` enters the view controller.The problem is that this action *jumps* and I would like it to animate, transitioning from it's current perspective to it's new position where the frames in the transition between the two points in space are represented.

I would like to have this happen on the `defaultCameraController` as well if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Mike, Try this post: 57586437 - it's ez to do ur own camera and then you can pretty much do whatever you want.  The default camera controller works - kinda, but it has limitations that you probably don't want long term.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to get the animation to work is to wrap your translation in an `SCNTransaction` block.

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 5
scnView.defaultCameraController.translateInCameraSpaceBy(x: 10, y: 10, z: 10)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Hey James! Thanks for the answer. Are you aware of a way to chain these, say to animate this back to it's original position?

Comment: SCNTransaction has a completion block that you could use to trigger another animation. However I think a better approach would be to create your own camera node and and animate it with SCNActions, it will give you much more control over what you can do.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, James.